# How to define a specific agent of a population of agents in AnyLogic?

Tags: agent, anylogic, population

I have a population of "passengers" agents in which every single agent of this population makes a request ("OrderPassenger" agent type ) to another "Airport" agent. The "Airport" agent, at this point, must respond to the request through an "AirportSuggestion" agent and send it to the specific "Passenger" of the "passengers" population.

I tried to use:
send (airportSuggestion, main.passengers (orderPassenger.passenger));
but orderPassenger.passenger is not an integer type.

I tried to use:
send (airportSuggestion, main.passengers (0));
but it is not said that the passenger (0) is the one who made the request.

What is the method to select that specific agent who made that specific request to the "Airport" agent?

Does an agent of a population of agents have an id number to identify it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make your Passenger agent the message that is being sent around.

So Passenger sends itself to Airport using `send(this, someAirport)`. Airport does it's thing and memorizes the passenger from the message using a local variable or directly in the "on message received" code box where the passenger is accesible using the "sender" keyword (check out how those work [here](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/the-magic-light-bulb-by-benjamin-schumann/)).

cheers

Comment: and then how does Airport send a response to the sender? 
The passenger makes a request to the Airport (by entering the code send(this, main.airport) and then the airport responds to this specific request made by that specific passenger. Once the response from the airport is received, the passenger must enter in a specific status of the Passenger statechart.
I created a variable called "sender" of "Passenger" type but it doesn't populate.

Comment: Well, use local variables, assign them when a message arrives and use them when you send messages again. Do check some example models or create a new specific question to address your new issue (else it gets too complicated to follow here).